# Dynamically changing Cell Renderer of ag-grid using param function in Angular 8

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Can someone help me out with this?
I'm using ag-Grid in Angular 8, where I have a column which has cell renderer as a single button (let's say Delete button), but when the grid fires cellValueChange Event i.e when a particular cell value change I want delete button cell renderer to get replaced with other cell renderers.

Here what I'm doing,

```js
columnDefs: {

    headerName: 'Delete'
    cellRenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {
        return getCellRenderer(params);
    }
}

getCellRenderer(params)
{
    if (params.value.isEdit)
        return 'updateRenderer';
    else
        return 'deleteRenderer';
}
```

`isEdit` is a hidden column in a grid whose value is set to 1 on event call, else by default it will be 0 for all rows.

So, this function should return the renderer. I have created frameworkComponent as below:

```js
frameworkComponent: {
    deleteRenderer: DeleteRendererComponent,
    updateRenderer: UpdateRendererComponent
}
```

Now, when I provide cellRenderer: 'deleteRenderer', I got a proper component rendered.
But when I call it through function I only got string printed as deleteRenderer, not the component.

Thank in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you combine both the cell renderers into one and decide the action based on the value of the field that you can pass as `cellRenderer` param.

Something like this -

```
cellRenderer: 'commonRenderer'
cellRendererParams: {
  editable : "isEdit" // pass the field value here
}
```

Inside your cell renderer component, you can access this editable param inside `agInit` like this -

```
agInit(params: any) : void {
    params.editable // here
}
```

Now you can branch off update/delete logic based on this passed parameter value.

Cell renderer component [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-angular-components)

Comment: Thanks, I got the path to follow from this one but have to implement many more things around it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you do it in the latest version of AgGrid.

```js
cellRendererSelector: (params) => {
  if (params.value.isEdit) {
    return {
      component: 'updateRenderer',
      params: {} // optional parameters
    };
  } else {
    return {
      component: 'deleteRenderer',
      params: {} // optional parameters
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with `cellRendererSelector` on Javascript as below :

```
const columnDefs = [
{
  headerName: "Name",
  field: "user.name",
  // apply the condition and render the component
  cellRendererSelector: (params) =>
    params.data.orders && { component: "agGroupCellRenderer" }, 
},

// ...rest of the items
```

]